# Using Commerce Feeds module, commerce file names are being changed when importing

Tags: commerce, files, feeds

I have an e-commerce site that sells albums. This product variation type of album has a field of type commerce file. It’s configured to have multiple files (mp3’s) attached, or bundled to it. I’m using the Feeds & Commerce Feeds module. Feeds uses csv files to create these products.

The Feeds importer works but the file names are being changed. It’s appending a ‘_0’ to the file name.

for example:
songname.mp3 -> songname_0.mp3 (see attached)

[image]

I’ve tried numerous different settings within the file sources option of the product variation type. I’ve checked and unchecked ‘File attach from server directory’ option

note - I have File Field Path module installed because the dirs. need to be different (dynamic) for each product. For example:

```
private://artists/artist_name/album_name/song_name.mp3
```

Utlimately what I want to do is create the dirs. and add the files to server myself and then have the Feeds importer simply reference files that are already there. I don’t want to copy or upload.

Any insight or help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to structure/feeds importer
2. Select yourproductimporter - go to mapping/.
3. Go to Files:URI (commerce_file:uri)
4. Click on the button below text "Rename if file exists."
5. Change to "Replace" and save the importer.  That worked for me.

That will eliminate the _0 or _1.mp3 and keep the same file name as your database.